# Visual Studio: How to make Cassini listen on ::1?

Tags: visual-studio, web, cassini, ipv6

Visual Studio's internal development web-server only listens for connections from the local computer.

Unfortunatly, the web-server only binds to the **IPv4** loopback address:

```
127.0.0.1
```

On machines with IPv6 enabled (i.e. Windows Vista, Window 7), it does not bind to the **IPv6** loopback address:

```
::1
```

When you push play in Visual Studio, or open the web-site from the notification area icon, the browser launches and tries to connect to "**localhost**":

```
http://localhost:53289/WebSite/
```

localhost is not a real address, but an alias. On Vista and later it is defined as:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

::1        localhost
```

So you cannot browse to the web-site running on the local host by trying to connect to **localhost**, you have to change it to 127.0.0.1

---

How can i make Visual Studio's internal web-server also listen on

```
::1
```

in addition to

```
127.0.0.1
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not use IPv6 with Visual Studio's development server. You can set it up with IIS however.

You can find instructions on how to do this here:  [http://blogs.iis.net/.../using-ipv6-with-iis7.aspx](http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2008/05/03/using-ipv6-with-iis7.aspx).

Another option is to do what I've done before, which is to remove the IPv6 localhost definition from your hosts file. Just remove this line:

```
::1        localhost
```

Make sure you include a reference to `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file as an alternative, otherwise you will have bigger problems. You should never need to use `localhost` as an alias for `::1`, at least until the world switches exclusively to IPv6, which won't be for a long time anyway.